# Added isCancelled flag in useEffect, but still getting "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component..."

Tags: reactjs

I created follow button component which cause a problem. It displays singularly on a tag page. On first load there is no error, but when I'm clicking other tag to display other tag's page then this error appears:

```
Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
in FollowButton (at TagPage.tsx:79)
```

All answers I found on the internet says about adding `isCancelled` flag in `useEffect` hook, which I did, but it didn't help at all.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FaRegEye } from "react-icons/fa";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import FollowInfo from "../models/dtos/read/FollowInfo";
import UsersService from "../services/UsersService";
import Viewer from "../models/Viewer";
import { ViewerContext } from "../ViewerContext";

interface Props {
  for: "user" | "tag";
  withId: number;
}

const FollowButton = (props: Props) => {
  //todo too much rerenders, button actually blinks at start and show wrong state
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [followInfo, setFollowInfo] = useState<FollowInfo | null>(null);
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

  console.log("follow rerender", followInfo);

  let viewer: Viewer = useContext(ViewerContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    let isCancelled = false;
    !isCancelled && setFollowInfo(null);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (props.for === "user") {
        !isCancelled &&
          setFollowInfo(
            await UsersService.amIFollowingUser(
              props.withId,
              viewer.currentUser?.token
            )
          );
      } else {
        !isCancelled &&
          setFollowInfo(
            await UsersService.amIFollowingTag(
              props.withId,
              viewer.currentUser?.token
            )
          );
      }
    };
    !isCancelled && fetchData();

    return () => {
      isCancelled = true;
    };
  }, [props, viewer.currentUser]);

  const follow = (what: "tag" | "user", withId: number) => {
    if (what === "user") {
      followUser(withId);
    } else {
      followTag(withId);
    }

    setFollowInfo((state) => {
      if (state != null) {
        return { ...state, doesFollow: true };
      } else {
        return { receiveNotifications: false, doesFollow: true };
      }
    });
  };

  const unfollow = (what: "tag" | "user", withId: number) => {
    if (what === "user") {
      unfollowUser(withId);
    } else {
      unfollowTag(withId);
    }
    setFollowInfo((state) => {
      if (state != null) {
        return { ...state, doesFollow: false };
      } else {
        return { receiveNotifications: false, doesFollow: false };
      }
    });
  };

  const followUser = (userId: number) =>
    makeRequest(() =>
      UsersService.followUser(userId, viewer.currentUser?.token)
    );

  const unfollowUser = (userId: number) =>
    makeRequest(() =>
      UsersService.unfollowUser(userId, viewer.currentUser?.token)
    );

  const followTag = (tagId: number) =>
    makeRequest(() => UsersService.followTag(tagId, viewer.currentUser?.token));

  const unfollowTag = (tagId: number) =>
    makeRequest(() =>
      UsersService.unfollowTag(tagId, viewer.currentUser?.token)
    );

  const makeRequest = (call: () => Promise<any>) => {
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    call().then(() => setIsSubmitting(false));
  };

  return (
    <>
      {followInfo == null ? (
        t("loading")
      ) : followInfo.doesFollow ? (
        <Button
          disabled={isSubmitting}
          variant="light"
          onClick={() => unfollow(props.for, props.withId)}
        >
          <FaRegEye />
          {t("following")}
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <Button
          disabled={isSubmitting}
          onClick={() => follow(props.for, props.withId)}
        >
          <FaRegEye />
          {t("follow")}
        </Button>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default FollowButton;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!isCancelled && setFollowInfo(await...)` checks the flag and schedules `setFollowInfo` to execute when data is ready. The flag may change during `await`.

Try this:

```
if (!isCancelled) {
    const data = await UsersService.amIFollowingUser(
        props.withId,
        viewer.currentUser?.token
    );
    !isCancelled && setFollowInfo(data);
}
```

Also check the documentation for [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController). It will be better to use it inside `UsersService.amIFollowing*`